# React useContext hook: context becomes null on page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following UserContext.js file, which stores the current logged in user into a user object, and also a setter function. In my Profile component, I want to pre-populate my input fields with the current logged in user's information, which I should be getting using useContext hooks.

The app works fine if I navigate to the Profile page normally from the homepage, but when I try to directly access /profile or reload the page while within the Profile page, I am seeing that my context becomes undefined for a split second (as seen by the console.log), before it loads a value. This causes the useEffect() hook and initializeFields() function to fail because the properties are null.

What I want to happen, is to be able to seamlessly load the current logged in user, and also use it globally in other components within the app. Passing the user object from the parent component as props is not feasible because in reality, my app is a few components deep and prop-drilling wouldn't be a very elegant solution.

```js
const UserContext = React.createContext({
  user: {},
  setUser: (user) => {},
});
```

In the App.js component:

```js
const App = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/profile" exact component={Profile} />
        </Switch>      
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
```

The Profile.js component:

```js
const DashboardProfileModal = (props) => {
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [username, setUsername] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  const [address, setAddress] = useState();

  console.log(userContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeFields();
  });

  const initializeFields = () => {
    setName(userContext.user.name);
    setUsername(userContext.user.username);
    setPassword(userContext.user.password);
    setAddress(userContext.user.address);
  };
```

Comment: I am confused, why you have setUser as value in your context. Have you tried user alone, which is the stateful object, you want to hold in the context? 2nd: why initialize all fields in the profile and put it to local state?

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann Sorry I failed to include the useState hooks in App.js, and these values are what I pass into the provider. For the 2nd: My Profile component contains input fields which should be editable, for when a user wants to change their information. I initialize them as the values from the user context:
For example: we have a logged in user named "bob". When bob goes to the Profile component, the field for name should have the string "bob" into it at startup.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like below and make sure that userContext is available before attempting to use it.

You should also at least make the `useEffect` run once on page load by adding the `[]` (else it will fire constantly on every render). I've also added `userContext` as a dependency to the `useEffect` and then I check `userContext` and `name`. This means it will ensure `userContext` is not `null` before it attempts to run your method.

Then I also include the `!name` check so that we can ensure it doesn't keep attempting to run your method once your state has been set for the first time.

```
const DashboardProfileModal = (props) => {
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [username, setUsername] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  const [address, setAddress] = useState();

  console.log(userContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(userContext && !name){
      initializeFields();
    }
  },[userContext]);

  const initializeFields = () => {
    setName(userContext.user.name);
    setUsername(userContext.user.username);
    setPassword(userContext.user.password);
    setAddress(userContext.user.address);
  };
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe the problem you're facing is because you have the provider declared on the `App` component. If you want it to be globally accessible to the whole application you should have it on your `index.js` file, wrapping the `App` component. Something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <UserContext.Provider>
        <App />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Comment: unless Profile is a child of the context provider, it does not matter, where it is located

Comment: This is incorrect and a misconception not worth spreading.  As long as the Provider wraps any component that needs to access the context, it doesn't matter how far down the tree it is.